# What is the equivalent to JUnit in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, junit

I am coming from Java and am currently working on a C# project. What is the recommended way to go about a) unit testing existing C# code and b) accomplishing TDD for C# development?

Also is there an equivalent to EMMA / EclEmma (free yet powerful code coverage tool) for Visual Studio and C# code?

Comment: IF another person says NUnit, I am gonna puke! Where TF did you people learn to read?

Comment: as I've already said to one of the "answers", the key word in my question is "recommended" - I had obviously heard of NUnit, but wanted to know whether it was the best one to go with. Sorry, should have added that to the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1 [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/)
2 [NCover](http://ncover.org/) or
3 [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/) (I never used it)

Comment: NCover is not free, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 9):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) is patterned after JUnit, but if you're using Visual Studio 2008 then consider the built-in unit testing framework.

Comment: Apparently, the first NUnit was simply the Junit source run through CSC to see what would compile.  They went through the minimal conversions necessary.

Comment: I use the built-in testing framework, but also install TestDriven.Net to get the nice right-click menu extensions that allow me to run individual tests and suites easily.

Answer (score 6):

Unit test framework: [NUnit](http://nunit.org)

Unit test runner: Various, but personally I like the one in [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper). (ReSharper costs money, but is easily worth it for the various productivity improvements.)

Coverage: [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) (I think this used to be free, but it now costs money. Hmm.)

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org) (formally mbUnit) for unit testing, and (unfortunately not free) NCover for code coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question about unit test frameworks:

[NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php) 1.0 was a direct port of JUnit. NUnit 2.0 moved away from JUnit syntax in order to take advantage of the .NET platform. [xUnit.net](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) is a newer unit test framework (from Jim Newkirk - one of the NUnit 2.0 developers - and Brad Wilson) that states as a goal exposing "advances in other unit test library implementations that have not really surfaced in .NET," which I read as "keeping up with JUnit."

Answer (score 2):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) would be it.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit, but NCover is only part of the answer as it isn't free. I've asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360) about that.

Answer (score 2):

VS2008 Professional has the Team System unit testing functionality baked in.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd install:

1. NUnit for your Unit testing framework http://www.nunit.org/index.php
2. Test driven.net for runing your tests http://www.testdriven.net/
3. Rhino Mocks as your mockign framework http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx

As and aside I find it odd that the NUnit guys seem to be using php to host their homepage...